# How to change the printed qweb filename

Tags: python, xml, odoo, qweb

How to change the printed qweb filename depends on the source document field name?
Im in the model stock.picking

So when i click the print -> Delivery note, then the qweb will be printed, but te filename will be depends on the Source document field. 
Here i present the picture that explain what i mean.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXZ7K.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give dynamic report name using configuration, but it will apply when you print one report.

Below is the example to **Print custom name** in report.**Create** one field in **ir.actions.report.xml**, in which user can configure **report name**.

```
from openerp import models, fields
class IrActionsReportXml(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.actions.report.xml'

    download_filename = fields.Char(
        'Download filename')
```

Now you need to create two files.

1. Report Controller

   ```
   from openerp import http
   from openerp.addons.mail.models import mail_template
   from openerp.addons.report.controllers.main import ReportController
   from openerp.addons.web.controllers.main import content_disposition


   class ReportController(ReportController):
       @http.route([
           '/report/<path:converter>/<reportname>',
           '/report/<path:converter>/<reportname>/<docids>',
       ])
       def report_routes(self, reportname, docids=None, converter=None, **data):
           response = super(ReportController, self).report_routes(
               reportname, docids=docids, converter=converter, **data)
           if docids:
               docids = [int(i) for i in docids.split(',')]
           report_xml = http.request.session.model('ir.actions.report.xml')
           report_ids = report_xml.search(
               [('report_name', '=', reportname)])
           for report in report_xml.browse(report_ids):
               if not report.download_filename:
                   continue
               objects = http.request.session.model(report.model)\
                   .browse(docids or [])
               generated_filename = mail_template.mako_template_env\
                   .from_string(report.download_filename)\
                   .render({
                       'objects': objects,
                       'o': objects[:1],
                       'object': objects[:1],
                       'ext': report.report_type.replace('qweb-', ''),
                   })
               response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = content_disposition(
                   generated_filename)
           return response

       @http.route(['/report/download'])
       def report_download(self, data, token):
           response = super(ReportController, self).report_download(data, token)
           # if we got another content disposition before, ditch the one added
           # by super()
           last_index = None
           for i in range(len(response.headers) - 1, -1, -1):
               if response.headers[i][0] == 'Content-Disposition':
                   if last_index:
                       response.headers.pop(last_index)
                   last_index = i
           return response
   ```

2.Report.py

```
    import json
    from openerp import http
    from openerp.addons.web.controllers import main
    from openerp.addons.mail.models import mail_template


    class Reports(main.Reports):
        @http.route('/web/report', type='http', auth="user")
        @main.serialize_exception
        def index(self, action, token):
            result = super(Reports, self).index(action, token)
            action = json.loads(action)
            context = dict(http.request.context)
            context.update(action["context"])
            report_xml = http.request.env['ir.actions.report.xml']
            reports = report_xml.search([
                ('report_name', '=', action['report_name']),
                ('download_filename', '!=', False)])
            for report in reports:
                objects = http.request.session.model(context['active_model'])\
                    .browse(context['active_ids'])
                generated_filename = mail_template.mako_template_env\
                    .from_string(report.download_filename)\
                    .render({
                        'objects': objects,
                        'o': objects[0],
                        'object': objects[0],
                    })
                result.headers['Content-Disposition'] = main.content_disposition(
                    generated_filename)
            return result
```

Odoo community Providing us a default module for report custom name. you can directly install this module and set report name like : ${o.name}

Here o means your record.

Below is a link of odoo community  module.

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/report_custom_filename/

This may help you.

Comment: THANKS YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR REPLY!

But i also had another code which is already works for me, but beside that i also looking forward from your code in the first place, your code really helps!

Answer (score 0):

try **attachment** in your reprot to change report file name as your desired name.

```
<report
            string="Delivery Slip"
            id="action_report_delivery"
            model="stock.picking"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="stock.report_deliveryslip"
            file="stock.report_deliveryslip"
            attachment="'Custom Text...'+'.pdf')"
        />
```

Comment: alright let me try then. But first of all im confuse in, what's the (object.state) means ?  should i change into something ?

Comment: it will display state of stock picking you can ignore it if you do not want it.

Comment: its still not working though, i wanted the filename is from the source document (field name: origin)

Comment: This option will be used for saving printed documents as attachments. Loading the attachment will ofcourse fulfill the requirement, but i think this will be bit late ;-)

Comment: Hi, i need to set boolean to true if delivery slip report is downloaded once. How could i do it? @alpesh

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my code which works for different reportname in the same model. So the filename only changes for the certain filename.

> 
from openerp.addons.web.http import Controller, route, request
from openerp.addons.web.controllers.main import _serialize_exception
from openerp.osv import osv
from openerp.addons.report.controllers.main import ReportController
from openerp import http
import simplejson
import logging

class SponsorReportController(ReportController):

    @route(['/report/download'], type='http', auth="user")
    def report_download(self, data, token):
        requestcontent = simplejson.loads(data)
        url, type = requestcontent[0], requestcontent[1]

        logging.info(url)
        logging.info(type)

        response = ReportController().report_download(data, token)

        if len(url.split('/report/pdf/')) > 1 and type == 'qweb-pdf':

            reportname = url.split('/report/pdf/')[1].split('?')[0]
            reportname, docids = reportname.split('/')
            logging.info(reportname)
            assert docids
            logging.info(docids)

            if reportname == 'pci_stock_picking_report.report_delivery_note':
                partner_obj = http.request.env['stock.picking']
                object = partner_obj.browse(int(docids))
                filename = "No."+(object.origin)
                response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s.pdf;' % filename)

        return response
```